# Restarting a task after being cancelled by a cancellation token

Tags: .net, vb.net, parallel.foreach, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

Initially I thought this ought to be simple and, surely, there is going to be an easy way to accomplish this. Now I am not so sure anymore. Here is what I want to do.

I am offloading a lengthy download task to a `Parallel.Foreach` loop to which I pass a `CancellationToken`. If the user clicks the "Cancel" button, the token's `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel` method is called and the loop terminates as it should.

I want the user to be able to cancel and re-start the loop as often as he wants but I don't know how to do this since you can only use a `CancellationTokenSource` once. I have to declare it as global variable in order for it to be visible in the Cancel-button event handler as well as in the code that starts off the `Parallel.Foreach` loop.

Here is the code (abbreviated to the essentials):

```
Public Class frmMain

    Private cTokenSource As New CancellationTokenSource

    Sub btnStart(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click

        InitialiseTiles()
        Dim t As Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()
                                                  Dim ParallelOptions As New ParallelOptions() With {
                                                                                                .CancellationToken = cTokenSource.Token,
                                                                                                .MaxDegreeOfParallelism = txtNTasks.Text,
                                                                                                .TaskScheduler = Nothing
                                                                                                }

                                                  Parallel.ForEach(Tiles, ParallelOptions, Sub(aTile)
                                                                                               Try
                                                                                                   Dim myWebClient As New WebClient
                                                                                                   myWebClient.DownloadFile(TMS & aTile, TilePath & aTile)
                                                                                               Catch ex As Exception
                                                                                                   Debug.Print("Got a problem: " & ex.Message)
                                                                                               End Try
                                                                                           End Sub)
                                              End Sub)


    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAbort_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAbort.Click
        cTokenSource.Cancel()
    End Sub

End Class
```

What's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just for posterity, here is the answer that [Hans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) suggested in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48703091/restarting-a-task-after-being-cancelled-by-a-cancellation-token#comment84405188_48703091) above:

I simply added the line

```
cTokenSource = New CancellationTokenSource
```

right after `InitialiseTiles()` at it works.